# Xamarin Forms | Scroll wheel like in iPhone alarm

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin.forms

On iPhone, if you go into the clock app and create a new alarm, there is a scroll wheel for selecting the time. I want to know how to implement that in Xamarin Forms for Android and iPhone.

Edit:
I want to have specific numbers like 12.5, 16.3, 4.6, etc. I don't want to have any in-betweens

Answer (score 0):

The control you're looking for is named `TimePicker` in Xamarin.Forms.